# Calculate the distance from current location to x objects and orders them with a filter from the nearest to the furthest

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop

I created two functions that calculates the distance from my location to a x car

```
func distance(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
    let from = CLLocation(latitude: from.latitude, longitude: from.longitude)
    let to = CLLocation(latitude: to.latitude, longitude: to.longitude)

    return from.distance(from: to)        
}


func selT(car:Car) {        
    guard let coordinates = car.location  else {
        return
    }
    self.destination = coordinates

    if currentLocation != nil {
        let dist = distance(from: currentLocation!, to: coordinates)
    }
}
```

and i have a function with which i download cars

```
func getOkToDownload(download:CarsToDownload?, error : Error?) -> Void {       
    if let download = download {
        self.download = download
        if download.status == "OK" {
            if let carsDownloaded = download.cars {
                var number = numberCars / (categories?.count)!
                number = number == 0 ? 1 : number    

                let distanceC = carsDownloaded

                cars.append(contentsOf: carsDownloaded)
            }

            self.tableView?.reloadData()
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: response.status, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.showCars(true)   
                }
            }))
            self.present(viewController: alert)
        }
        showing = false
    } else {
        print("response is nil")
    }
}
```

where "cars" is  `var cars: [Car] = []` and "download" is of type `CarsToDownload` so `download.cars` are the cars that i'm going to download, now what i want to do is to create a filter that order in this function (`getOkToDownload`) the cars i downloaded from nearest to fairest, to do that i think i have to create a cycle that calculate all the distance of the `carsDownloaded` and once i have obtained the values, order the array with a filter but how can i do it? Considering i get the distance value of a x car with those external functions i showed to you, for now i only added in my `Car` class this parameter `var distanceT: Float?` (don't know if it could be useful)

Answer (score 0):

The actual computation of what you need is just two things: filtering your collection for distance and sorting that collection by distance. I threw something together in Playground to illustrate the process. The only real lifting below is two lines of code: filtering and sorting.

```
let mileMultiplier = 0.000621371

let home = CLLocation(latitude: 34.043017, longitude: -118.267254)
let loc1 = CLLocation(latitude: 32.689596, longitude: -117.999806)
let loc2 = CLLocation(latitude: 33.556666, longitude: -117.659812)
let loc3 = CLLocation(latitude: 34.043017, longitude: -118.467254)
let loc4 = CLLocation(latitude: 35.501326, longitude: -116.751808)
let loc5 = CLLocation(latitude: 33.986546, longitude: -117.454548)

let collection = [loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4, loc5]

func geoQueryCollection(collection: [CLLocation], radiusInMiles: Double, sorted: Bool) -> [CLLocation] {
    let results = collection.filter { $0.distance(from: home) * mileMultiplier < radiusInMiles }
    return sorted ? results.sorted { $0.distance(from: home) < $1.distance(from: home) } : results
}

let results = geoQueryCollection(collection: collection, radiusInMiles: 200, sorted: false)
results.map { print(Int($0.distance(from: home) * mileMultiplier)) }
// prints: 94, 48, 11, 132, 46

let results2 = geoQueryCollection(collection: collection, radiusInMiles: 50, sorted: true)
results2.map { print(Int($0.distance(from: home) * mileMultiplier)) }
// prints: 11, 46, 48
```

You'd probably want to cache the distance computations so you don't make them twice, in addition to other likely refinements suited to your need, but this is the starting point.